# Trying to change the output of Get-Date into an integer?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to take output from Date-Time in Powershell and change it into an integer (rather than a date-time object or a string) so I can subtract it from another date later.

I have two variables:

```
$nowBase = Get-Date
```

and

```
$loopTime = Get-Date # which will be used later for the aforementioned math.
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `[datetime]` is already a "subtractable" type. `$loopTime - $nowBase` will give you a `[timespan]` object representing the difference

Comment: And if you really want a number (`[Long]`), you can use the [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8) property : *The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 in the Gregorian calendar*